# Data transformation in matplotlib.mlab PCA

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca

I'm trying to understand how PCA works with `matplotlib.mlab`

I know that `Wt` are the principal components, `mu` is the means vector and `Y` is the transformed matrix.

Shouldn't you get the transformed matrix if you substract the means from the original matrix and then dot product to the PCs?

Then why aren't the outputs for the following print statements the same?

```
data = numpy.random.random((5, 4))
pca = PCA(data)
print numpy.dot(data - pca.mu, pca.Wt)
print pca.Y
```

Comment: Try adding a `data` sample  to the example. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @Lucas. I added the data sample line.